# SQL Query that retrieves all columns from one table and one column from the another

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume we have the following tables:

```
Products [ItemID,ItemName,ItemDesc]
ProductInSupermarket [ItemID,SupermarketID,ItemPrice]
```

and we want to retrieve all from `Products` and `ItemPrice` from `ProductInSupermarket`, is there any way to do that without mentioning all the columns? I mean, we can do:

```
  Select Products.ItemID,Products.ItemName,Products.ItemDesc,ItemPrice 
    FROM Products,ProductInSupermarket 
    WHERE Products.ItemID=ProductInSupermarket.ItemID;
```

but this is not so readable when we have a table with many columns and we want to retrieve the all from this table and some of another table. How can I write this query in a more readable and efficient way?

Comment: `SELECT Products.*, ProductInSupermarket.ItemPrice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I echo [@DCoder's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250041/sql-querry-that-retrieves-all-columns-from-one-table-and-one-column-from-the-ano/16250079#comment23249889_16250041), but add that you can also omit giving table qualifiers where there is no ambiguity and use explicit join syntax with `USING` to be even more concise:

```
SELECT Products.*, ItemPrice
FROM   Products JOIN ProductInSupermarket USING (ItemID)
```